# Can't export IOS app archive from xcode for AdHoc Deployment

Tags: ios, xcode, error-handling, compiler-errors, ipa

After archiving successfully my app using a mobile provisioning profile for ad-hoc distribution, when I try to export it using the Organizer window in Xcode, I get a strange message which is Given Below.

[image: See this image for better representation]

Comment: Have you tried to close the xCode completely, open again and export? I have never seen such a long error log from Organizer.

Comment: Firstly Thanks for the reply and for giving your precious time.Actually this happens when I include Bitcode at the time of exporting the archive file.I already done close the xcode completely and then open and export but nothing works.